# Using Wireshark with gRPC

Tags: grpc, wireshark, http2, wireshark-dissector

I am trying to dissect TCP packets carrying gRPC payloads with Wireshark.
Although I configured decoding as http2 and provided path to my .proto directory, Wireshark seem to only decrypt TLS data, and doesn't show the actual content.

I am using a gRPC client and server in localhost and chose the loopback interface.
Also, I followed guidelines in grpc.io site: https://grpc.io/blog/wireshark/

[image]

Will appreciate assistance on how to properly dissect the packets and show as expected from the guide (the guide is just a reference for what I am trying to achieve here)

Comment: What's your wireshark version? Only after v3.3.0 can parse protobuf content.

Comment: The version is v3.4.5, seem to be ok

Comment: Try samples on https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/How-to-Export-TLS-Master-keys-of-gRPC

Answer (score 1):

I had tried with the guide, and it's worked well as expected.
I guess can't decode protobuf content caused by .proto file configuraiton.

[image: content]

And then choose protobuf, and edit search path, the first config is the PATH of proto file. It should be directory, not file. And then, choose load all files, then it should be worked.
[image: serch path]

Comment: Seems like that after decoding the TLS layer and showing all TCP transport, I can't access the data. If you look at the picture I attached the last layer that shows content is the transport layer showing TCP payloads. Maybe I am missing some other configuration?
What I done so far: decoding tcp, port 5001 with http2 and adding the directory of the .proto files to Protobuf search paths

Answer (score 0):

The solutions may include:

1. To decode as "TLS" if it is gRPC messages over tls.
2. If the TLS is dissected correctly but HTTP2/GRPC is not dissected, and you compiled wireshark in linux by yourself, you may need to install following optional libraries before recompiling wireshark:

- `Gcrypt (libgcrypt)` That causes the HTTP2 frames in TLS1.3 to be decrypted.
- `nghttp2`  HTTP2 dissector uses this lib to parsing http2 headers that include grpc stream information.

You can get the libraries information from here https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/